# Function doesn't get executed

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, linker

I want to understand the following scenario as what exactly happens.
I have a shared library(A) which loads another shared library(B) by dynamic loading.
Library A exposes few methods(F1) as well.

The main program loads the library, A and then library A loads library B at later point.
Now When library B tries to uses function F1 from the library A, it fails to load its symbol, and compile stops execution silently without giving any warning/error or core. Even though I can see these symbols exported from the library A(using nm command).
I am not very sure what exactly happening. I observed this on Linux.64.
The same scenario on windows work.

Comment: How did you tried to compile that?

Comment: if they are dynamic libraries, what has the compiler got to do with it? I don't see the link..

Comment: What he said. Did you compile the libraries yourself and are they aware they're running on a 64 bit system and how does B know about the functions in A?

Comment: Library A header file do have method F1 defined which library B is trying to use. So the compilation will go fine.

Comment: So B does have access to the header of A? OK. Just checking.

Comment: do you manually load (i.e. `dlopen`) or if not, can you check to see if the libraries are found on the path (i.e. when you run `ldd` on the binary - do you see all the libraries found)

Comment: Yeah I compile both libraries by my self.

Comment: when I run ldd on the library B, I can see library A in the dependency.

Comment: Upvoting; this is worthy of an answer. I don't have any ideas though. Sorry.

Comment: How are you loading library A?  Are you linking at compile time (-l) or are you using dlopen()?

Comment: main program loads library A dynamically.

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean by 'dynamically', you mean using dlopen().  Are you sing `RTLD_GLOBAL` as one of the options to dlopen()?

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that because you tagged this as C++ you're compiling C++ code. I also guess that you used slightly different options to compile libraries A and B, causing their name decoration and/or ABI to be incompatible, and thus the method(s) can't be found.

Have you considered just letting the linker apply all the shared objects to your application rather than using `dlopen`? Then you'd know straight away that there was a problem because the linker couldn't match the symbols.

Alternately perhaps Linux just doesn't like your circular library references: can you refactor your libraries to eliminate the circular dependency?

Comment: Yeah I am refactoring my code. But I just wanted to understand what went wrong.